# Kill while redirecting output in C doesn't really kill

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, system-calls, kill

I have a parent process in which I have a while loop. In that while loop I create children(count times). If an error occurs in any child, I want nothing else to be written to the standart output, only the first error message.

When an error occurs, I want the program to shut down all children and the parent, how do I do that. I am trying:

```
while(count--) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid > 0){
      wait(NULL); 
      if(execlp(command1,command2,(char *)NULL) < 0){ // error occured
        char str[1024] = "errr";
        perror(str); 
        sprintf(str, "kill -SIGINT %d >> /dev/null 2>&1",getppid());  
        system(str); 
      }
  }
```

but it's not working, it prints the error multiple times

I want to terminate/kill the program when a single error happens so that no other message is printed

count is 5, command1 and command 2 are "ls"

Comment: Your parent process sits around waiting for its child to die, but the child goes back around the loop and forks again, and the first child now waits for its own child to die before messing with the `execlp()` which, if successful, would replace the parent process. Since you see error messages, the `execlp()` must be failing. Since each of the many processes gets the failure, you get lots of messages.  It is hard to know what you’re trying to do, but it is clearly not what you’re actually doing.

Comment: Incidentally, it would be a lot easier to help you if you show your code. Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: I am trying to terminate/kill the program when a single error happens so that no other message is printed

Comment: Incidentally, `str` should be initialized before it is passed to `perror`, or `perror` could be passed 0 or `""` instead.

Comment: Maybe you should call `kill()` to send SIGTERM to all the processes in your process group, after setting up the initial process as the process group leader. But without knowing what you’ve been taught, it’s hard to guess what might be appropriate.  Your code doesn’t detect all errors, nor do the processes exit on reporting an error.  Using system to run the `kill` command is very heavyweight processing.  Call the kill function instead

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how do I set up the process leader?

Comment: @KarinaK: Your code creates `count` processes, each of which runs simultaneously with others, and each of which prints an error quickly, before there is time for the kill signal to be sent (except maybe some are killed in time). If you want only one error message, you must add some way of coordinating the processes. You must either run them one at a time or must make them check with each other before printing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil they should run all at the same time

Comment: Use `setpgrp()` or perhaps `setsid()`.  It’s all good clean fun.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm nowhere using `setsid()`

Comment: That might be a problem.  Or it might not. I still don’t understand what you’re trying to do or how your code is supposed to be doing it.  It all looks wrong, but I can’t tell what’s right because I don’t understand what you’re trying to do.

Comment: @KarinaK: If they all run at the same time, they all do their own thing. That is the whole point of having separate processes. If you want only one to print, they must communicate with each other and coordinate which one prints. You can use locks, semaphores, or other interprocess communication.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler adder more info

Comment: You’ve not shown what `count` is set to, or `command1` or `command2`.  Your condition that has the parent wait for its child to die before it goes on its merry way as if nothing went wrong is puzzling.  You’ve not shown whether you set up signal handling. You mention I/O redirection but don’t show it. Please post an MCVE as already requested.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler added them at the bottom of the question

Comment: Has your class discussed locks or semaphores? Or atomic objects?

Comment: @EricPostpischil not at all

Comment: @KarinaK: Then I suspect the intent of the assignment is for the parent to fork a bunch of children, for each child to attempt a command and to exit with a status that indicates success or failure, and for the parent to wait for the children to exit and to print an error message if any child reported a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to give the processes a way to communicate with the parent and on failure in ANY child have the parent print an error.